# How to make a jQuery plugin (the right way)?

Tags: jquery, design-patterns, jquery-plugins, refactoring

I know there are jQuery cookie plugins out there, but I wanted to write one for the sake of better learning the jQuery plugin pattern.

I like the separation of "work" in small, manageable functions, but I feel like I'm passing `name`, `value`, and `options` arguments around too much. Is there a way this can be refactored?

I'm looking for snippets of code to help illustrate examples provided with in answers.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

### example usage

```
$.cookie('foo', 'bar', {expires:7});
$.cookie('foo'); //=> bar
$.cookie('foo', null);
$.cookie('foo'); //=> undefined
```

### Edit:

I did a little bit of work on this. You can view the revision history to see where this has come from. It still feels like more refactoring can be done to optimize the flow a bit. Any ideas?

### the plugin

```
(function($){

  // the utility function
  $.cookie = function(name, value, options) {

    // cookies enabled?
    if (!navigator.cookieEnabled){
      return false;
    }

    // get
    if (typeof value == 'undefined') {
      return get(name);
    }

    // set
    else {
      options = $.extend({}, $.cookie.defaults, options || {});
      return (value != null) ? set(name, value, options) : unset(name, options);  
    }
  };

  // default options
  $.cookie.defaults = {
    expires:  null,
    path:     '/',
    domain:   null,
    secure:   false
  };

  // private functions
  var set = function(name, value, options){
    return document.cookie = options_string(name, value, options);
  };

  var get = function(name){
    var cookies = {};
    $.map(document.cookie.split(';'), function(pair){
      var c = $.trim(pair).split('=');
      cookies[c[0]] = c[1];
    });
    return decodeURIComponent(cookies[name]);
  };

  var unset = function(name, options){
    value = '';
    options.expires = -1;
    set(name, value, options);
  };

  var options_string = function(name, value, options){
    var pairs = [param.name(name, value)];
    $.each(options, function(k,v){
      pairs.push(param[k](v));
    });
    return $.map(pairs, function(p){
      return p === null ? null : p;
    }).join(';');
  };

  // prepare each key=value pair
  var param = {
    name: function(name, value){
      return name + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value);
    },
    expires: function(value){
      // no expiry
      if(value === null){
        return null;
      }
      // number of days
      else if(typeof value == "number"){
        d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (value * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
      }
      // date object
      else if(typeof value == "object" && value instanceof "Date") {
        d = value;
      }
      return "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
    },
    path: function(value){
      return "path="+value;
    },
    domain: function(value){
      return value === null ? null : "domain=" + value;
    },
    secure: function(bool){
      return bool ? "secure" : null;
    }
  };

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Why do you expose the cookie utils?

Comment: @svinto, how can I do it differently? :)

Comment: I wonder if he was referring to creating a cookie plugin that already exists (http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cookie).

Comment: @Lancy May, this plugin is loosely based off that plugin, yes. Again, the purpose of this project was to better learn how to organize jQuery plugins/utility functions. I wanted to see a more true jQuery style plugin rather than a giant single function.

Answer (score 2):

This is an excellent tutorial on using TDD to [turn your jquery code into a richer unit testable plugin](http://www.onenaught.com/posts/85/turn-your-jquery-code-into-a-richer-unit-testable-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/learn-how-to-create-a-jquery-plugin/

This will help u..

Comment: No offense, but just skimming over it, this the worst jQuery plugin tutorial that I think I've ever seen.